# How to delete a personal IMAP mail folder in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, imap

I'm running Outlook 2013 in Windows. I have an IMAP account. It's not a 365 or Exchange account so I can't use OWA to manage it.

I foolishly copied the Sent mail subfolder (root Inbox) outside the Inbox, in the same account folder. Outlook won't allow me to delete the folder (it's greyed out in the options list) and it doesn't appear on my webmail page.

How can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Everything in Outlook is MAPI-based, so you can use [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) for "raw" access. (Works with local folders, IMAP folders, and Exchange folders.)
2. Since it's an IMAP account, you can connect to the same server from any other IMAP client and delete the folder from there – Thunderbird would be the usual choice, there's also Claws (or Outlook Express / Windows 7 Mail back in the day), probably a few less known ones.

Comment: MFCMAPI is some program! But I don't have the expertise to use it, and in any case, it doesn't list the additional file I created.

Comment: And I really don't want to go to all the trouble of adopting another client.

Comment: I used the instructions for deleting a folder using MFCMAPI from this web page...  https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/hidemovedeletemfcmapi.htm#delete . But although the process was easy, the folders weren't deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f3935b07-ece1-4e51-8cd6-32afab3be8a0/outlook-folder-will-not-delete-imap?forum=outlook). try "Outlook /resetnavpane" command switch and then delete again.